# Convert multiple .py file to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qprocess

I am trying to convert my python program to an executable (.exe) file using PyInstaller, I have 2 python fils: `dummy_script.py` and `GUI.py`.

Basically, `GUI.py` consists of a button that executes `dummy_script.py`.

`dummy_script.py`:

```
import sys
import time


def flush_then_wait():
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stderr.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)


sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 1\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 2\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 3\n")
sys.stderr.write("Total time: 00:05:00\n")
sys.stderr.write("Total complete: 10%\n")
flush_then_wait()

sys.stdout.write("name=Martin\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 4\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 5\n")
sys.stderr.write("Total complete: 30%\n")
flush_then_wait()

sys.stderr.write("Elapsed time: 00:00:10\n")
sys.stderr.write("Elapsed time: 00:00:50\n")
sys.stderr.write("Total complete: 50%\n")
sys.stdout.write("country=Nederland\n")
flush_then_wait()

sys.stderr.write("Elapsed time: 00:01:10\n")
sys.stderr.write("Total complete: 100%\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 6\n")
sys.stdout.write("Script stdout 7\n")
sys.stdout.write("website=www.mfitzp.com\n")
flush_then_wait()
```

`GUI.py`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit,
                                QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QProgressBar)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
import sys
import re

# A regular expression, to extract the % complete.
progress_re = re.compile("Total complete: (\d+)%")

def simple_percent_parser(output):
    """
    Matches lines using the progress_re regex,
    returning a single integer for the % progress.
    """
    m = progress_re.search(output)
    if m:
        pc_complete = m.group(1)
        return int(pc_complete)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.p = None

        self.btn = QPushButton("Execute")
        self.btn.pressed.connect(self.start_process)
        self.text = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)

        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.progress.setRange(0, 100)

        l = QVBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(self.btn)
        l.addWidget(self.progress)
        l.addWidget(self.text)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(l)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

    def message(self, s):
        self.text.appendPlainText(s)

    def start_process(self):
        if self.p is None:  # No process running.
            self.message("Executing process")
            self.p = QProcess()  # Keep a reference to the QProcess (e.g. on self) while it's running.
            self.p.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handle_stdout)
            self.p.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handle_stderr)
            self.p.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state)
            self.p.finished.connect(self.process_finished)  # Clean up once complete.
            self.p.start("python",["dummy_script.py"])

    def handle_stderr(self):
        data = self.p.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        # Extract progress if it is in the data.
        progress = simple_percent_parser(stderr)
        if progress:
            self.progress.setValue(progress)
        self.message(stderr)

    def handle_stdout(self):
        data = self.p.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("utf8")
        self.message(stdout)

    def handle_state(self, state):
        states = {
            QProcess.NotRunning: 'Not running',
            QProcess.Starting: 'Starting',
            QProcess.Running: 'Running',
        }
        state_name = states[state]
        self.message(f"State changed: {state_name}")

    def process_finished(self):
        self.message("Process finished.")
        self.p = None


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

w = MainWindow()
w.show()

app.exec_()
```

The concept used to execute `dummy_script.py` in `GUI.py` is:

```
p = QProcess()
p.start("python3", ['dummy_script.py'])
```

Now when I pack the whole program in an executable using PyInstaller, `dummy_script.py` is missing.

How can I make sure `dummy_script.py` gets included in the PyInstaller bundle?

Reference: https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qprocess-external-programs/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Side note, unless you have a specific need to use `sys.stdout.write()` and `sys.stderr.write()` directly, it's much easier (and more idiomatic) to simply use [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print). That uses standard out by default, and you can `print("foo", file=sys.stderr)` for the error stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The concept used to execute (dummy_script.py) in (GUI.py) is,
>
> ```
> p = QProcess()
> p.start("python3", ['dummy_script.py'])
> ```

PyInstaller is pretty good at finding and bundling dependencies, but it won't be able to figure out that `GUI.py` needs `dummy_script.py` if you run it this way.

A better approach would be to *import* the code you need and use it directly, e.g something like

```py
from dummy_script import some_function


some_function()
```

### Other options

If you simply modify `GUI.py` like this, [PyInstaller should find `dummy_script.py` on its own](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs).

If that is not practical for some reason, you should be able to declare it as a hidden import [using a spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html). You may have a spec file from an earlier build, but if you need to create a new one you can do that with something like this:

```
pyi-makespec GUI.py
```

Then edit the spec file to add `dummy_script` to the list of hidden imports:

```
a = Analysis(['GUI.py'],
     # ...
     hiddenimports=['dummy_script'],
     # ...,
)
```

Then build again from the modified spec file:

```
pyinstaller foo.spec
```

That may not work either, since you still aren't `import`ing the other module. In that case you may need to declare it as [a data file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) instead.

Comment: Thank You so much, but can you suggest me how can I implement dummy_script.py in GUI.py, what changes should I do in GUI.py

Comment: An example of how you might change `GUI.py` is already in my answer: `import` some or all of `dummy_script` into `GUI.py`, then call whatever function you need to call. What isn't shown is changes you might have to make to `dummy_script.py`. You'll probably want to wrap up its functionality (at least the part you want to execute from `GUI.py`) in a function.

Comment: With the example above, that might mean defining a `run` function that contains all of your prints and flushes. You'd import and call `run()` in `GUI.py`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Chris has you covered with a great answer. If you have any further issues with pyinstaller.

Additional references:https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

I use the following:
pathex to find additional paths for imports
hiddenimports = missing or not visible in the python scripts. Sometimes modules have hidden imports themselves.
datas = all data from a module

Sometimes a hook is required, an example hook used for Hydra:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import 
collect_data_files,collect_submodules
datas = collect_data_files('hydra.conf.hydra')
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('hydra')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).